# From C# - Call Jquery methods

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

We need to have below functionality, we need to create c# method as below

```
public string JquerySelection(string htmlString, string jQuerySelector)
{
// htmlstring:  Will have entire html of a webpage.
// jQuerySelector Will be as: $("#intro").html()
// $("#intro").html() ->    Element with Id as intro and it's html content.
// Hence element with id "intro" will be searched in htmlString and returned its value.
}
```

Could anyone suggest, what C# code needs to written for this ?

Comment: JavaScript is run on the local client, so will have no relation to any C# code you execute. Instead look at C# Parsers, such as the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), which can read the value for you.

Comment: Thanks Rory, Yes I can use HTMLAgilityPack. But we need to implement jQuery selector functionality. With HtmlAgilityPack we can use XPath to perform same action. Can htmlagilitypack used for jquery selector functionality ?

Comment: If you're trying to parse external html page, @RoryMcCrossan are right - HtmlAgilityPack, if you want generate some html/javascript from server code like c#, you can use ScriptManager.

Comment: https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery

Comment: Probably this may help as well - http://linqjs.codeplex.com/ - Linq To jQuery.

Comment: Thanks to all, I think CsQuery or Fizzler will help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

C# runs on server side and JQuery runs on client side. There are some libraries which allow to do jquery on server side with ASP.NET, but using them are highly discouraged since it involves a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a javascript function from server side (c#), but not sure of with jquery.
 This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11098/Use-Call-RegisterStartUpScript-RegisterClientScrip) provides an overview of tha same.

**RegisterStartupScript** function from ScriptManager class in System.Web.UI namespace will help to acheive the same